# Tabelas não sendo geradas - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jpa

Estou com 2 tabelas do meu software que não estão sendo geradas corretamente. É gerado o SQL, mas ao verficar no MySQL, não as encontros.

Se mudo a tag para: `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>` ou `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>`, a primeira me apresenta o erro que não há a tabela ban, e na segunda, ele da um create nas tabelas ban e desativado.

Stack:

```
Type Exception Report

Message A MultiException has 2 exceptions. They are:

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistence_unit_juntos] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on br.com.felipejunges.juntos.controller.PessoaController

    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:487)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistence_unit_juntos] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on br.com.felipejunges.juntos.controller.PessoaController

    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:391)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:767)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:706)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:318)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistence_unit_juntos] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:884)
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    br.com.felipejunges.juntos.repository.PessoaRepository.<init>(PessoaRepository.java:20)
    br.com.felipejunges.juntos.controller.PessoaController.<init>(PessoaController.java:21)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1350)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:271)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:365)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:767)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:706)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:318)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [ban]
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:130)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.performValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:100)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:67)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    br.com.felipejunges.juntos.repository.PessoaRepository.<init>(PessoaRepository.java:20)
    br.com.felipejunges.juntos.controller.PessoaController.<init>(PessoaController.java:21)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1350)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:271)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:365)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:767)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:706)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:318)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

**Modelos com erro:**
Classe ban:

```
package br.com.felipejunges.juntos.entity;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="ban")
public class Ban {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private BigInteger id;

    @Column(name="banInicio")
    private Timestamp banInicio;

    @Column(name="banFim")
    private Timestamp banFim;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="usuario_id")
    private Pessoa usuario_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="admin_id")
    private Pessoa admin_id;

    @Column(name="reativado")
    private Timestamp reativado;

    public Ban(){

        }

    public Ban(BigInteger id, Timestamp banInicio, Timestamp banFim, Pessoa usuario_id, 
            Pessoa admin_id, Timestamp reativado){
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.banInicio = banInicio;
        this.banFim = banFim;
        this.usuario_id= usuario_id;
        this.admin_id = admin_id;
        this.reativado = reativado;

    }

    public BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Timestamp getBanInicio() {
        return banInicio;
    }
    public void setBanInicio(Timestamp banInicio) {
        this.banInicio = banInicio;
    }
    public Timestamp getBanFim() {
        return banFim;
    }
    public void setBanFim(Timestamp banFim) {
        this.banFim = banFim;
    }
    public Pessoa getUsuario_id() {
        return usuario_id;
    }
    public void setUsuario_id(Pessoa usuario_id) {
        this.usuario_id = usuario_id;
    }
    public Pessoa getAdmin_id() {
        return admin_id;
    }
    public void setAdmin_id(Pessoa admin_id) {
        this.admin_id = admin_id;
    }
    public Timestamp getReativado() {
        return reativado;
    }
    public void setReativado(Timestamp reativado) {
        this.reativado = reativado;
    }

}
```

Classe Desativado:

```
package br.com.felipejunges.juntos.entity;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="desativado")
public class Desativado {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private BigInteger id;

    @Column(name="desativadoEm")
    private Timestamp desativadoEm;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="evento_id")
    private Evento evento_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="admin_id")
    private Pessoa admin_id;

    @Column(name="reativadoEm")
    private Timestamp reativadoEm;

    public Desativado(){}

    public Desativado(BigInteger id, Timestamp desativadoEm, Evento evento_id, 
            Pessoa admin_id, Timestamp reativadoEm){
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.desativadoEm = desativadoEm;
        this.evento_id = evento_id;
        this.admin_id = admin_id;
        this.reativadoEm = reativadoEm;

    }

    public BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Timestamp getDesativadoEm() {
        return desativadoEm;
    }
    public void setDesativadoEm(Timestamp desativadoEm) {
        this.desativadoEm = desativadoEm;
    }
    public Evento getEvento_id() {
        return evento_id;
    }
    public void setEvento_id(Evento evento_id) {
        this.evento_id = evento_id;
    }
    public Pessoa getAdmin_id() {
        return admin_id;
    }
    public void setAdmin_id(Pessoa admin_id) {
        this.admin_id = admin_id;
    }
    public Timestamp getReativadoEm() {
        return reativadoEm;
    }
    public void setReativadoEm(Timestamp reativadoEm) {
        this.reativadoEm = reativadoEm;
    }

}
```

**E um modelo funcionando:**

Classe Pessoa:

```
package br.com.felipejunges.juntos.entity;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="pessoa")
public class Pessoa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="nome")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name="sobrenome")
    private String sobrenome;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="senha")
    private String senha;

    @Column(name="telefone")
    private String telefone;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Cep.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="cep")
    private Cep cep;

    @Column(name="login")
    private Timestamp login;

    @Column(name="registro")
    private Timestamp registro;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="gacesso_id")
    private Permissao gacesso_id;

    @Column(name="banAtivo")
    private boolean banAtivo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="localizacaoAtual")
    private Localizacao localizacaoAtual;

    public Pessoa() {

    }

    public Pessoa(int id, String nome, String sobrenome, String email, String senha, 
            String telefone, Cep cep, Timestamp login, Timestamp registro, 
            Permissao gacesso_id, boolean banAtivo, Localizacao localizacaoAtual) {

        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
        this.email = email;
        this.senha = senha;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.cep = cep;
        this.login = login;
        this.registro = registro;
        this.gacesso_id = gacesso_id;
        this.banAtivo = banAtivo;
        this.localizacaoAtual = localizacaoAtual;


    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getSobrenome() {
        return sobrenome;
    }
    public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
    }
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }
    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }
    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }
    public Cep getCep() {
        return cep;
    }
    public void setCep(Cep cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }
    public Timestamp getLogin() {
        return login;
    }
    public void setLogin(Timestamp login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
    public Timestamp getRegistro() {
        return registro;
    }
    public void setRegistro(Timestamp registro) {
        this.registro = registro;
    }
    public Permissao getGacesso_id() {
        return gacesso_id;
    }
    public void setGacesso_id(Permissao gacesso_id) {
        this.gacesso_id = gacesso_id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Localizacao getLocalizacaoAtual() {
        return localizacaoAtual;
    }

    public void setLocalizacaoAtual(Localizacao localizacaoAtual) {
        this.localizacaoAtual = localizacaoAtual;
    }

    public boolean isBanAtivo() {
        return banAtivo;
    }

    public void setBanAtivo(boolean banAtivo) {
        this.banAtivo = banAtivo;
    }
}
```

Link do projeto no Git: https://github.com/felipeejunges/juntos

Comment: Teste com `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nas tabelas geradas, a variável utilizada é **BigInt**, ao hibernate converter para SQL, o mesmo convertia para **Decimal(10,2)**, tentei criar o SQL como o gerado, e não criava as tabelas, então  mudei para int, e agora está sendo gerado.